# SQL Server Ce : Dataset Insert And Refresh

Tags: c#, insert, dataset, sql-server-ce, refresh

I have this query for inserting data into my dataset, but after inserting nothing is added into database!

I'm not sure how it can make it work...

Here is my query :

```
MyDataSet Rs = new MyDataSet();
MyDataSetTableAdapters.StudentTableAdapter da = new MyDataSetTableAdapters.StudentTableAdapter ();
MyLDataSet.StudentTable dt = newMyDataSet.StudentTable();

da.InsertData("Name", "TT", "C1222", DateTime.Now);
```

Looking forward to hear some advice....

Answer (score 1):

You should call the Update method to save your changes.

```
tableAdapter.Update(dataSet.TableName);
```

Comment: You can see an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: i did and even after updating, and refreshing database there is still no data inside!

Comment: How are you previewing the data?  Are you using a GridView our are you look at the table data directly in Visual Studio?

Comment: You may need to refill your dataset.  Here's an example.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171920.aspx

Comment: im looking at Database , i dont want to populate anything... I try both but Database still Empty! i know i have to refresh or do something after insert but seems non of this commands are helping!

Comment: da.Update(dt);
                da.Update(Rs);
                da.Fill(dt);
i use all this 3 commands,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using custom classes to insert data (I'm not familiar with InsertData), so you'd need to post additional code.  With that said, here is a basic way to insert data in SQL Server CE:

```
using(SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(connStr)
{ 
    con.Open(); 
    SqlCeCommand qry = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO TableName (ColName) VALUES (@ColName)", con);

    qry.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColName", "ColName Value");
    qry.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

Good luck.